# Simulating 32x32 Radar Configuration from 64x64 FMCW Radar Data

Tags: downsampling, radar

I have gathered data using an FMCW Radar with a configuration of 64 chirps per frame and 64 samples per chirp. Now, I'm trying to simulate the data as if it were collected by a radar with a 32x32 configuration. Specifically, I am interested in applying cropping techniques, either on the raw data or the Range-Doppler map, to replicate the data that would have been obtained from a 32x32 radar.

I've experimented with subsampling methods, such as taking alternate samples and selecting the first half of the samples, but these approaches didn't succeed.

Is it possible to so this? If so, what needs to be done?

Comment: You need to be specific. Nobody but you knows what a 32x32 radar is.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I mean a radar with a configuration of 32 chirps per frame and 32 samples per chirp

Comment: You need to ask specific questions if you want good answers. This is not a specific question but rather a very vague one. What are the parameters of the collected data? What the parameters of the desired output data? Pulse lengths? Bandwidth? The more information and the more finely tuned the question, the more likely you are to get an answer.